# Why functional interface used in Java Lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I know how a functional interface works in Java lambda expression.
But just wondering whey Java don't provid some types (Function or Lambda) to define lambda expression e.g. Lambda l = () -> xxxxxx;

I understand use interface can have backward compatibility.
But why defining a new data type is not a good practice(override??)

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question correctly. Are you asking why we not write something like `... new Comparator<Foo>{ @Override public int compare(Foo lhs, Foo rhs) { ... } };` ?

Comment: Have you seen the [various `java.util.function` types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html)? If you haven't: e.g. `Supplier<Xxxxxx> xSupplier = () -> xxxxxx`. If you have seen them, can you clarify your question?

Comment: Lambda expressions can have varying return types and parameters, with the parameters having different names. A functional interface provides documentation explaining what the method is supposed to do, as well. How would you propose providing all that functionality in just two new types? (And your last sentence is unclear to me - it would be good if you could clarify it.) Basically, it's unclear exactly what you think *should* have happened instead of using functional interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But just wondering whey Java don't provid some types (Function or Lambda) to define lambda expression e.g. Lambda l = () -> xxxxxx;

IMHO, there are few reasons not to provide new type (interface basically):

- Because child function is function interface so the Function / Lambda interface must be a Marker Interface. In this case FunctionalInterface annotation does same, even better job. We have it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html
- But why we choose annotation instead of marker interface even they share same meaning? If you have Function / Lambda interface, that is mean all instances are interchangeable. And when initial lambda, how Java could know which interface function to apply? It is problem.